# How to implement multiple language in zend framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, internationalization

I want to implement multi language in my site using zend framework.

I need step by step solution, i got some solution but not able to understand.

Thanks in advance.

Kanji

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following link will help you

http://www.tornstrand.com/2008/03/29/string-localization-with-gettext-and-zend-framework/

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`Zend_Translate`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.html) for this.

You have to

1. Decide which adapter you want to use;
2. Create your view and integrate Zend_Translate in your code;
3. Create the source file from your code;
4. Translate your source file to the desired language.

The reference manual explains these steps in further detail. You might also be interested in

- [Devzone: Zend Framework and Translation](http://devzone.zend.com/article/4513)
- [ZendCasts: Introducing Zend_Translate](http://www.zendcasts.com/introducing-zend_translate/2009/11/)